# How to write a func that returns a func that returns a Generic type

Tags: go, generics

I have the following go code which **DOES NOT COMPILE**

What I am looking for is how to write a func that returns a func that returns a generic type

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
)

type logAndReturnDefault[T constraints.Ordered] func(input T) T

func iWillRewturnAFunc(name string) logAndReturnDefault{
    return func(input string){
        log.Println("I am in the func that will be returned as a returned value")
    }
}

func Add[T constraints.Ordered](a T, b T) T {
    i := iWillRewturnAFunc("ABC")
    return a + b + i
}

func main() {
    result := Add(1, 2)
    result2 := Add(1.2, 3.4)
    log.Printf("", result)
    log.Printf("", result2)
}
```

My intention is to use `iWillRewturnAFunc` to return a `func` that can return a ***generic*** type.

But of-course I am failing, as I am not able to identify the syntax for the declaration of `iWillRewturnAFunc` func.

Answer (score 1):

There is some mismatch between what you want to achieve and your code.

A generic function is nothing but a generic type, so a function returning a generic type must be generic:

```
func iWillRewturnAFunc[T constraints.Ordered](name string) logAndReturnDefault[T] {
    return logAndReturnDefault[T](func(input T) T {
        var t T
        ...
        return t
    })
}
```

But what you are trying to do is to return a specific instance for string, which can be done:

```
func iWillRewturnAStrFunc(name string) logAndReturnDefault[string] {
    return func(input string) string {
        log.Println("I am in the func that will be returned as a returned value")
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Burak for the response. You are right, my code was not correct and what I am looking for is the 1st approch (To return a func that can return a generics and not only a string) but the code you provided also does not compile directly. (I change `t` to a return value) can you check ?

Comment: You have to compute t somehow. See the edit

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. In the below code **NOW COMPILES AND RUNS**.

The return Type of generic is decided by the `Add` function. will be provided to the nested function as both are using the same generic interface `T constraints.Ordered` .

Just like this, There is a way to work with 2 different Generic type as well. by defining `U constraints.Ordered (or any other interface)` .

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
)

type LogAndReturnDefaultFunc[T constraints.Ordered] func(T) T

func iWillReturnAFunc[T constraints.Ordered](name T) LogAndReturnDefaultFunc[T] {
    log.Println(name)
    // or do something with the *name"
    return LogAndReturnDefaultFunc[T] (func(input T) T {
        t := name
        log.Println(input)
        // Do something with input
        return t
    })
}

func Add[T constraints.Ordered](a T, b T) T {
    // Call `iWillReturnAFunc``, that will return a func
    returnedFunc := iWillReturnAFunc(a)
    // Run the returned func to get its o/p
    outputOfReturnedFunc := returnedFunc(b)
    //Do something with the Output of the func
    log.Println(outputOfReturnedFunc)
    return a + b + outputOfReturnedFunc
}

func main() {
    result := Add("abc", "DEF")
    result2 := Add(1.2, 3.4)
    log.Printf("%v\n", result)
    log.Printf("%v\n", result2)
}
```